# Specifics of downvotes

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I have a question about my Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Strange resistance between two adjacent but unlinked nets on veroboard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391603/strange-resistance-between-two-adjacent-but-unlinked-nets-on-veroboard)

This question is downvoted -2, I want to know is there a way to find out the reasons for downvote and then improve the question and then request for cancellation of downvote ?

Even if the downvote is irreversible action yet there should be a way to figure the reasons for downvote so that those irregularities or bad presentation may be taken care of in the next questions.

If you don't know what went wrong then how can you rectify it in next phase? It's like living in the darkness.

I think along with downvote there should be a compulsory comment input as well for the downvoter.

Comment: The downvote button has a mouse over text. Sometimes this text is just what you want to say, so no further comments necessary. Also when someone leaves feedback, people may downvote for the same reason without stating it again.

Comment: This will just be a guess from OP's point of view and won't help enough, if OP had already taken care of the _"hover text"_ then she's got nowhere to start from, so it's again a guess game

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is frustrating to receive downvotes with no corresponding critique. However, voting in general is anonymous for good reasons, so commenting is strictly voluntary. This has been [debated many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=downvote+mandatory+comment), and this state of affairs is generally accepted as the best compromise.

In your particular case, the very first comment is a critique that might explain the downvotes. Since you have since edited the post, the original voters can come back and change their votes if they feel the problem has been resolved.

Also, when you reply to a comment, it's a good idea to notify the person you're replying to by putting "@*<username>*" in your reply. Then you can be sure they'll see your response and they might reconsider their vote.

And one further comment: The large number of large, out of focus pictures is not helping at all. You need to get or borrow a better camera and take a limited number of pictures that are relevant to the specific problem.

Comment: thanks! that helps in finding maximum available options, yet could you possibly post a link where I can read this anonymous down-voting debate to help me figure out some other possible solution to this problem because it's not affecting only me, I'm sure there are other users too who want to get through this, like one solution could be "the down voting should be anonymous but there must me a comment with no identity".

Comment: OK, see the link I added above. But you're just going to have to accept the situation as it is. The idea of (optionally) anonymous comments isn't going to fly, either.

Comment: You're right but we ought to think for other possible solutions as well. I'll give it a shot later.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't see that question originally.  Now that I have, I have downvoted it for the terribly out of focus pictures.  Those are volunteer abuse.

*Think* about it.  Would you hand in homework like this?  Of course not.  Now consider why.  It would be rude to the teacher, and you'd probably get a bad mark as a result.  Now consider your teachers are *paid* to look at your homework, but everyone here is a volunteer.

Dumping sloppy work on us basically says *"Eh, you lot don't matter.  You peons are privileged just to read whatever I choose to throw your way.  So fork over the answer already!"*.  We can't make your grade one level lower, but we can downvote.  So we did.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your input as it helped me figure and decide taking off the bad pictures and putting only one edited pic of my perboard layout which if not exactly what is needed yet is better than all previously removed pictures.

Comment: Secondly you are wrong about volunteer abuse theory in my this questions' specific case as I didn't just went posting this question I did a lots of work prior to posting this question. I don't respect anyone (personal ideological reasons) but I do care about and love many, And communities like Open-Source, Mozilla, Stack-Exchange and like are my 2nd most beloved and cared communities and I would only wanna help these communities rather abusing.

Comment: Olin, you're worth every penny we pay you.

Comment: @W5VO: Doh! And I thought I was worth at least twice what you pay me.